# Finding the largest Odd Fibonacci number in the given ranges of values

Tags: java

Ex: n1=100, n2=250, out=233.

Here I have to find the largest odd fibonacci number in the given set of ranges. If an odd fibonacci number doesn't exist then it should return 0. I am getting output as 50 times 0's and then 10 times 233. Where is my mistake and how can I get the desired output?

```
public class Fibo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int n1 = 100;
            int n2 = 250;
            int res = 0;

            if (n1 % 2 == 0) {
                n1 += 1;

                for (int i = n1; i < n2; i += 2) {
                    if (isPerfectSquare(5 * i * i + 4) || isPerfectSquare(5 * i * i - 4))
                        res = i;
                    System.out.println(res);
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ignored) {
            System.out.println("0");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPerfectSquare(int num) {
        double sqrt = Math.sqrt(num);
        int x = (int)sqrt;
        return Math.pow(sqrt, 2) == Math.pow(x, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code! Your IDE should indent and format everything for you.

Comment: *Please edit me* Sorry; I don't have an editor for *Akshay* installed on my computer, and I can't find one with Google either. Maybe you should talk to your doctor?

Comment: Your problem will reveal itself if you follow the advice here: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  You really need to learn how to do this yourself, and now is a good time to learn.  The duck knows ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static int getLargestOddFibonacciBetween(int lo, int hi) {
    assert lo <= hi;

    int f0 = 0;
    int f1 = 1;
    int res = -1;

    while (f1 <= hi) {
        int val = f0 + f1;
        f0 = f1;
        f1 = val;

        if (val >= lo && val <= hi && isOdd(val))
            res = val;
    }

    return res;
}

private static boolean isOdd(int val) {
    return (val & 1) == 1;
}
```

Comment: Answers should include some explanation / reasoning (e.g. what did the OP do wrong?), not just code - see OP's question: "Where is my mistake and how can I get the desired output?"

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Fibonacci {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the starting range");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the ending range");
        int r = sc.nextInt();
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = n; i <= r; i++) {
            if (isPerfectSquare(5 * i * i + 4) || isPerfectSquare(5 * i * i - 4))
                res = i;
            }
        System.out.println("The biggest odd number in the range is"+"  "+res);
    }

    public static boolean isPerfectSquare(int num) {
        double sqrt = Math.sqrt(num);
        int x = (int)sqrt;
        return Math.pow(sqrt, 2) == Math.pow(x, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Abhijit and welcome to StackOverflow. You could improve on your answer by providing some context as to why your code solves the problem, or how it accomplishes this.

Comment: I just did a little modification in the existing code to get the desired output. It really solved the problem. Because in this case the control always moving to the catch block initially and printing 0 so many times and while printing the value of res, that print statement is executing it for all the values and it is repeating the value 233.So, the print statement should be outside the for loop. We can also get the desired output without using try or catch in this case , as we are not getting any exception.